# Why is my background image not changing on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use a single background image that is 3 pixels wide and 89 pixels tall. Each 1 pixel vertical stripe will be the background of a different `div`.

I assumed that shifting the `background-position` by `-1px 0` and setting the `background-size` to `1px 89px` would change the background image on each `div`, but it does not. Here is the javascript that sets the background css.

```
(function () {
jQuery(".featuredBox").each(function (index, elem) {
    jQuery(elem).css({
        "background-image": "url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jJv2.png)",
            "background-position": -index + "px 0",
            "background-repeate": "repeat-x",
            "background-size": "1px 89px"
    });
});
})();
```

Here is a fiddle that shows what I'm trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/DGWsD/

=======================================

Here is a link to the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jJv2.png

Comment: Did you really spell it "background-repeate"?

Comment: It was a typo, but was not causing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You misspelled repeat.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".featuredBox").each(function (index, elem) {
        $(elem).css({
            "background-image": "url(http://i.imgur.com/mC7DQlt.png)",
            "background-position": -index + "px 0",
            "background-repeat": "repeat-x",
            "background-size": "1px 89px"
        });
    });
});
```

Also, no need for immediately invoking expressions `()` at the end of your function. jQuery does that for you.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DGWsD/2/)

Answer (score 1):

you can't use a part of image as background using background-size CSS property. background-size will scale the image to given size it will not take a part of it. and background-position will be applied to whole background, NOT to individual part of repeated image. So you can,t repeat that 1px*89px of 3px*89px horizontally.
you can try this at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp
and one more thing to notice it background-size will not work below IE9.

A quick solution for this was using photoshop or paint cut the image into 3 parts 1px*89px and paste them vertically and you can use background-position,backround-repeat with appropriate postion values to repeat it horizontally

Comment: The OP isn't wanting to crop/cut the image at all. ??

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to crop them. The end result would be three boxes that each have a slightly different background color. I suppose I could just use three separate images but I thought the spritesheet approach would  be better.

Comment: @ZeroDivide Ahh... I see.

Comment: @ZeroDivide hey, you can definitely use sprite but use a vertical sprite rather than horizontal one which you are using now.